# C++ UI Invoke not Working

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2013, clr

When debugging,I found my program have stopped after

> myServer->Invoke(myServer->myShowMessage);

I tried to find where it goes,and I set several breaks but I didn't find where it was going.However,I also set a break on ShowMessageMethod where it should go but I am sure it wasn't going to there.It was just look like dealing with other things and trapping in it.I suspect there was something wrong with the UI thread,but I have little knowledge about the underlying in Windows Message. I have create some other threads in main thread, is that makes things all different? I just followed the Invoke method code on msdn. And Here are my codes:

```
Server::Server(){
        InitializeComponent();
        myShowMessage = gcnew ShowMessageDelegate(this,&Server::ShowMessageMethod);
    }

System::Void Server::start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
        Thread^ myThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this,&Server::ListenThreadFunc));
        myThread->Start();
    }

void Server::ShowMessageMethod(){
        String^ message = "Get Successful";
        this->APTBX->AppendText(message);
    }

void Server::ListenThreadFunc(){
        ServerListen^ mySL = gcnew ServerListen(this);
        mySL->ListenThread();
    }

ServerListen::ServerListen(Server^ _s){
        myServer = _s;
    }

void ServerListen::ListenThread(){
        array<Object^>^myStringArray = { convert.toStringDelegate(information) };
        Object^ re = myServer->Invoke(myServer->myShowMessage);
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a deadlock to me. Could you try changing `Object^ re = myServer->Invoke(myServer->myShowMessage);` to `myServer->ShowMessageMethod()`? Does it stop now as well? This is not the answer to your question but should give us more insight on what's going on.

Comment: It didn't stop as before and it goes to the methoed it should call,however it warning me i am not visit the TextBox by the thread it was created.

Comment: I think I'd better read about the windows message and I may find out  how the invoke going.